# ios7 CGRect property not found on object

Tags: uiimage, nslog, cgrect

I tried using the following code to NSLog the dimensions of an `UIImage` but am receiving a warning that "Property 'theImage' not found on object of type ...." What am I doing wrong?

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.jpg"];

CGRect imageContent = self.theImage.bounds;
CGFloat imageWidth = imageContent.size.width;
CGFloat imageHeight = imageContent.size.height;

NSLog(@"Size of my Image => %f, %f ", imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should code like this:

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.jpg"];
CGSize imageContent = theImage.size;
CGFloat imageWidth = imageContent.width;
CGFloat imageHeight = imageContent.height;

NSLog(@"Size of my Image => %f, %f ", imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

Comment: I'd missed the `UIImage` angle. +1!

Comment: perfect .. thanks 377!

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH2g-C016212

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says; whichever class you've put that code into doesn't have a property named `theImage`. You probably instead meant:

```
CGSize imageContent = theImage.size;
CGFloat imageWidth = imageContent.width;
CGFloat imageHeight = imageContent.height;
```

Use the `self.` notation to access properties of that instance of the class. Local variables are a separate concept and so are accessed in a separate way. Instance variables have the same lifetime as the instance of the class. Local variables have only the lifetime of the enclosing scope (the method in this case).

In addition, as per user3779315, `UIImage` has a `size` but does not have `bounds`. That's because it has no `origin`. It's not part of any sort of layout hierarchy; it's standalone.